# Synchronization variants

Tags: java, synchronization

What is the difference between the two synchronizations:

```
public synchronized void set (int i) { 
   this.i = i;
}
```

and

```
public void set (int i) {
       synchronized (this) {
               this.i = i;
         }
    }
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394976/what-is-the-difference-between-synchronizedthis-and-synchronized-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are different ways of writing the same thing. Java could have just had the second form. Synchronizing the whole body of a method on the method's `this` object is a particularly common case, so the language provides a quick, simple way of doing it.

The Java Language Specification states the equivalence in [8.4.3.6 synchronized Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#8.4.3.6). `synchronized void bump() { count++; }` has exactly the same effect as

```
void bump() {
    synchronized (this) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First one is synchronized method and second one is synchronized  block.

Here as you `synchronized` on this object in block both represent same. In `synchronized-method`  thread acquire the lock of current object.

**Note:** in synchronized block you can synchronize block of code instead whole method body, as well use different resource for locking(except this).

Answer (score 1):

- first case : whole method is synchronized
- second case: only block of code in synchronized for which `synchronized(this)` is written

So if you write second method as

```
public void set (int i) {
       // Code here is not synchronized
       synchronized (this) { // only this block of code is synchronized
               this.i = i;
         }
       // code after this is also not synchronized. 
    }
```

But in case of second block, you can also synchronize of some other object.

```
public void set (int i) {
       synchronized (someObject) {
               this.i = i;
         }
    }
```

Comment: But it is the same, isn't it?

Comment: @ceving, your example would be funcionally the same. But if you want a method that should be be completely synchronized but only a code blcok from it, then you'll have to use second approach

Comment: I could write an extra method for this code block.

Comment: @ceving, yes you can, but if you write a separate method and synchronize it, you can't synchronize on some other object as mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

These two synchronisation methods are equivalent because you gave `this` in the `synchronized block`.

The synchronization is based on the **Intrinsic Lock** or **Monitor Lock**, an attribute of each Object

As the other answers stated your first proposition is a `synchronized method` which means that the thread will acquire the lock of the current Object.

From the Oracle Tutorials :

> When a thread invokes a `synchronized method`, it automatically acquires the intrinsic lock for that method's object and releases it when the method returns. The lock release occurs even if the return was caused by an uncaught exception.

Your second proposition is a `synchronized block` or `synchronized statement`. In this case the thread acquire the lock of the object put in argument.

Again from the Oracle Tutorials :

> Unlike synchronized methods, synchronized statements must specify the object that provides the intrinsic lock:

In your case you put `this` so it will take the lock of the current object as the synchronized method did.

But you can also give it another object and it will take its lock leaving the current object lock "unchanged"

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the two synchronizations, but the second one is more flexible: you can add unsynchronized code outside the `synchronized` block in the same method, or synchronize on an object different from `this`.